# Как форму вернуть в положение Enabled = true?

Tags: c#, winforms

При нажатии кнопки на форме я ставлю `this.Enabled = false;` а при нажатии на другой форме кнопки добавить и/или отмена - вернуть предыдущей форме состояние `Enabled = true`?

```
RegOS r = new RegOS();
r.Enabled = true;
```

Пробовала так, не получается, подскажите как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо где-то хранить ссылку на форму для которой вы установили `Enabled = false`, в главном окне например. Сейчас вы создаете новую форму и устанавливаете свойство в ней.

Answer (score 2):

Во второй форме нужно иметь ссылку на первую и изменять именно её, а не совершенно новый-другой объект.